# Beggining in funcional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, self-learning, learning

I get bogged down with notation as well as its mechanics and am in need of a textbook. What are good begginer's textbooks for functional analysis? Thanks.

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate, as there are already many good suggestions on the linked post. However, if you are truly a beginner with little exposure to measure theory and topology then Kreyzsig is the way to go, as his exposition is very clear, and it is fairly self contained.

Answer (score 0):

These are very basic one

[1 FA](https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjmyvPgvcHZAhXMHCsKHcKnD2kYABABGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_1ujlRBgyXYDuGWN2_iIymQEGJkIA&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjv6-3gvcHZAhUJrI8KHbWBAMkQ9aACCOkB&adurl=)

[2 FA](https://www.flipkart.com/functional-analysis/p/itmefb8hadazdbgw?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2snUBRDfARIsAIGfpqEojveU6KNs2-cyqDqynO4dCcvXyt51pG1avPXdunBdFBiPjcF44tsaAoaXEALw_wcB&pid=9788123929767&lid=LSTBOK9788123929767FATPYZ&cmpid=content_book_8965229628_gmc_pla&tgi=sem%2C1%2CG%2C11214002%2Cg%2Csearch%2C%2C170219493259%2C1o4%2C%2C%2Cc%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&s_kwcid=AL%21739%213%21170219493259%21%21%21g%21299142545466%21&ef_id=WoK3NwAAALCPcROf%3A20180225162745%3As)

Now beginning from a standard book

[3 FA](https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjEjdeWvsHZAhUTHisKHSGFANcYABABGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_2XwJ17yjz4Hynf9wBt9tBlTPOyBg&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwiMp9GWvsHZAhWCrY8KHagSAMMQ9A4IdA&adurl=)

[4 FA](https://www.amazon.in/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-Applications-Kreyszig/dp/8126511915?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=6c8d2176-9ac8-4467-82d3-eb7f13ba4af2)

This is the most viewed

[5 FA](https://www.amazon.in/Course-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387972455?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=6c8d2176-9ac8-4467-82d3-eb7f13ba4af2)

Hope this helps.